# How to cancel a google map marker drag operation?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, draggable, marker

As you see in the following code,  the Markers are draggable. In some cases, If a marker is dropped in a wrong area(polygon) I would like to cancel the drop event and consequently the marker come back to its original location automatically.

```
function placeMarker(latlng, color, isDraggable) {
    var marker = new GMarker(latlng, { icon: getIcon(color), draggable: true });
    map.addOverlay(marker);
    GEvent.addListener(marker, "dragend", function () {
        //redraw polygons again
    });
    GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
        var latlng = marker.getPoint();
        map.openInfoWindowHtml(marker.getPoint(), latlng.y + ", " + latlng.x);
    });
    return marker;
}
```

The question is how can I cancel the drag event of marker when it's already dropped in `dragend` event?

Comment: Why not just use an InfoWindow to show the marker's lat/lng, and not make the marker draggable at all?

Comment: Just declare their draggable property as false and their clickable property as true. They will still listen to clicks and mouseover events.

Comment: @MattBall I need to be draggable.

Answer (score 3):

Still couldn't find any solutions after these years, and yet again encountering this issue. I wish there was `event.cancelDrag()`to call.

All I can think of is to check if the marker belongs to `mypolygon` if not move it back to where it was before:

- On `dragstart` save the current location as `preLocation`
- on `dragend` use `containsLocation(e.latLng, mypolygon)`

  - yes => do nothing
  - no: set the marker location to `preLocation`.

[google map containsLocation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/poly-containsLocation)

[google map Events](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events)

Answer (score 1):

I don't remember that Google Map API support it but you can serve this functionality for yourself by saving markers' movements to a stack and extracting old position when you need it.
I know it isn't irrefragable answer. It just general idea. But I hope it will helpful.

Comment: Really, why you don't whant to make the marker undraggable at all?

Comment: That's the method which is implemented here: [Duncan's blog -- Google Maps API – locked draggable markers](https://duncan99.wordpress.com/2015/03/21/google-maps-api-locked-draggable-markers/)